# How can I implement ios in app purchase subscription model?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription

I couldn't find any tutorial which describes the implementation of in app purchase **subscription** model.If anyone know,please post.Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the official Apple guide to In-App Purchases. There's a section specifically dealing with Auto-Renewable Subscriptions.

[In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)